# How to remove unnamed branch in git shown in Github network view

Tags: git, github, git-branch

In the Github's network view of my git repository, there is a "phantom" branch that has no name. Please see the picture below.

For the sake of simplicity I would like to remove the black branch (leaving only the blue branch).

How can this be done?

[image: left side]
[image: right side]

Some of the labels with the hash:

[image: One commit]
[image: One commit]
[image: One commit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume the black branch starts at Commit A, and ends at Commit Z. Both A and Z are the blue dots. In the cmd, A and Z are the commit sha1.

```
git rebase --onto Z^2 A master
```

This makes a linear history. But if doing so, you must `git push origin -f master:master` to update the remote master by force and inform every member to fetch and track the new master and abandon the old one.

Comment: Thank you. Does the command change if the blue line is not the master branch, but a branch called "develop" (that branches from master in the first dot on February 27)? Thanks

Comment: @VictorP Yes, just change `master` to `develop`. In case you might regret, run `git branch backup_develop develop` to create a backup branch first, which can help get everything back easily.