# Remove duplicate unnamed branch from Git

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have somehow manage to create a duplicate of every commit I have made to a repository in an unnamed branch, as shown below on GitHub's network graph:

[image]

What can I do to clean this up and remove the duplicated commits?  I have looked at [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113359/how-to-remove-unnamed-branch-in-git-shown-in-github-network-view), but it seems to apply more to individual duplicates than to an entire duplicated branch.

**Additional information:**
I am the sole owner and user of the repository.  The issue first arose when I made a commit from a new computer, but did not properly set my username and email address.  I rectified this commit using the methods [posted here on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/).  After doing this, I was prompted to pull from the remote repository to my local repository before pushing some additional changes I had made, at which point it pulled the set of duplicate commits.

Comment: Did you look this post ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-to-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @MuratGündeş I'm not sure how to implement that given that right now the only branch that exists, remote or local, is the `master` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, Git does not have unnamed branches at all.  In another sense, it has an infinite number of unnamed branches.  Either way it makes little sense to attempt to display all of them<sup>1</sup>—and a GitHub network graph doesn't.  That's not what a GitHub network graph *is*.

[This is what a GitHub network graph is.](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer)  It attempts (not entirely successfully, in my opinion :-) ) to display the union of multiple *related* (by GitHub-fork, I presume) repositories.  Thus, what you are seeing is not necessarily anything in your own repositories, but rather across several different repositories, maybe including some of your own, but maybe literally *everything* is in several other repositories entirely.  It *might* be in your repository, but it might not be.  There is not enough information in your existing question to diagnose this

Since Git largely works by *adding new commits* (while keeping every old commit, through what Git calls *references*), most things you do will simply add more commits, and perhaps even more lines, to your network graph.  [ElpieKay's answer to your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38113665/1256452) works by *copying* commits, which would—and does—add another line, but making sure that the *first* copied commit has a link back to some existing commit (that's the `--onto` target of the rebase) and then removing the name that Git used to find the original chain of commits (that's the final step of `git rebase` itself).

In other words, this (at least conceptually—ElpieKay's answer is specific to one particular situation, ending in a merge commit, that I'm not drawing here) takes:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- main-branch

*--*--*   <-- side-branch
```

and first adds a *copy* of the bottom row, but with a link back to the top:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- main-branch
          \
*--*--*    *--*--*   <-- HEAD
```

(I omitted the `side-branch` label partly to save space, and partly because it sits "under" the copied commits: it still points to the last of the original three commits, though.)  Once the copying is done, we "forget" the original three by changing just the one branch label, giving:

```
o--o--o--o   <-- main-branch
          \
           *--*--*   <-- side-branch
```

The three original commits are forgotten precisely *because* they no longer have a name, `side-branch`, pointing to their *tip* (latest) commit.

One can accomplish this kind of thing with two different Git commands, which have different aims:

- `git rebase` copies some (usually small and simple) set of commits, preferably a simple linear chain, to a new set of commits, also changing the stored snapshot for each copied commit.  This is essentially equivalent to doing a series of `git cherry-pick`s on each to-be-copied commit.  Then, as we just saw, it moves the branch label so that instead of pointing to the last of the pre-copy commits, it points to the last of the post-copy commits.
- `git filter-branch` copies an arbitrary set of commits, including merges if you like, to a new set.  During this copying, each extracted commit snapshot is modified according to / using arbitrary filtering of your choice.  This may include omitting some commits, creating new commits, changing the parent linkages of commits, and/or making arbitrary changes to the snapshot.  This is therefore *much* more flexible than rebase, but also *much* **much** more difficult to use (and not well suited to the kind of source-tree modification rebase is specifically designed for, either).

**Whether any of this will help depends on what GitHub is showing you.**  Because a network graph is not limited to *your* repository, there is no guarantee that doing anything *within* your repository will improve anything you see.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Every* commit can be treated as an anonymous branch, or perhaps even an infinite number of anonymous branches (though the latter is not useful, while the former sometimes is).

One time when it does make sense to show an anonymous branch is when looking at a repository with a "detached HEAD".  This is because a detached HEAD literally means that the name `HEAD` resolves to one specific commit, making that one specific commit *act like* a branch-tip commit.  In effect, `HEAD` is the name of this branch.  But `HEAD` is *supposed* to move, or be "re-attached".  [(Your HEAD is there to move you around.)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKKqLl_ZEEY)  As soon as you move it, the commit stops being the tip of that anonymous branch.

In the steps shown above for rebase, I show `HEAD` pointing to the copied tip commit.  That is in fact how Git does the rebase, using `HEAD` as the tip of an anonymous branch.  The last step, moving the original branch's name, cements the copies into place permanently (permanent, that is, until you rebase again, or delete the name entirely).

Comment: if it makes things more clear, I've posted some additional information on the repository and how it got to the point that it's at right now.

Comment: Ah, that definitely helps. When you ran `git filter-branch` you copied *every* commit, altering them during the copy (in that period between extracting the original and making the one ones). Then you ran `git pull`, and `git pull` is always a bad idea. :-) In Git, pull means "fetch then merge": so you picked up all your original commits (well, you still had them, just "virtually" picked up) and then *combined* your new copies with your originals. You must now decide which set of commits to keep, and which get their name(s) deleted, *and* you must discard the merge and copy subsequent commits.

Comment: The decision on which to keep is going to be based on which have the right author/committer names. Discarding merges while keeping subsequent commits is usually easiest using `git rebase`. The precise command(s) to use depends on your repository.

Comment: Alright.  It's easy enough to see which set to keep and which to remove; I'm trying to use `git rebase -i`, but I get a merge conflict with every change, whether its a squash or drop.  You say that the precise command depend on my repository; how can I determine that?

Comment: Use `git log --graph` to get Git to draw the graph for you (I like to use, as one put it, A DOG: `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, here). Note that `git rebase -i --onto <target> <limit>` will copy commits from `<limit>` through `HEAD`, excluding any merges, to go after the named `<target>`.

Comment: Alright... I've set my `<target>` as the first commit in the set of commits that I want to overwrite, and the `<limit>` as the first commit in the set of commits that I want to keep, with both `<target>` and `<limit>` being duplicate commits of each other.  When I try to rebase this, I get a very long list of working tree files that would be overwritten by checkout, and the statement `Please move or remove them before you switch branches.`  The rebase then aborts.  The list appears to include every single file in the repository; what am I doing wrong now?

Comment: I'm not sure off-hand exactly what's wrong, but this part certainly *sounds* wrong: "I've set my target as the first commit in the set of commits that I want to overwrite". Rebase doesn't *overwrite* anything, it copies; the first copied commit has the `--onto` target as its parent, which means that this target commit is the commit that comes just before the new chain. It's a good idea to draw the graph, identify the commits you want to copy, and then do "git log limit..HEAD" to make sure those match up. Then the `--onto` is simply the last (most tip-ward) commit to *keep*.

Answer (score 1):

If by unnamed branch you mean dangling commits then `git gc --prune=all` should do the trick. But before running this command, make sure you don't have any of them, because this action is irreversible.

[More on `git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc)

Then you can execute `git push --prune` to remove remotes without a local counterpart.